# How can I have shiny or flexdashboard listening outside events like file changes?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app to monitor the change of a certain file directory. Per tips from @Shree, the function `shiny::reactivePoll` seems to be the answer. Yet I encountered another question.

```
#### ui.r
setwd(getwd())

library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(imager)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("TEST"),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput(
              inputId = "SN",  
              label = "Iput any number from 7 to 12", 
              value = "11"
              )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h3(paste0("image:")),
    imageOutput("Display")
  )
)) 

##### server.r
setwd(getwd())

library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(imager)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactivePoll(1000, session,
    # This function returns the time that log_file was last modified
    checkFunc = function() {
      IMG <- paste0("C:/Windows/Web/Wallpaper/Theme2/img",input$SN,".jpg")
      if (file.exists(IMG))
        print(file.info(IMG)$mtime[1])
      else
        print("No such file.")
        ""
    },
    # This function returns the content of log_file
    valueFunc = function() {
      load.image(IMG) %>% plot # the function and images are OK.
    }
  )

  output$Display <- renderImage({
    data
  })
})
```

SN value is obtained from ui.r, and passes to server.r, and it seems work, However, there is another problem that the image can't be properly produced and displayed.

1. SN is obtained from ui.r
2. the image file name is properly assembled in server.r
3. with the file name, the image is load and plot (to ensure), then sent into the container named `Display` via the variable `data`. (in the server.r)
4. the ui.r shall receive the `Display` and plot it.

but the result is [image: the type is not subsettable]. It seems the value passed is not what I think. Error happens between 3 & 4.
Please advise where and what I go wrong. Many thanks.

Comment: looking at `?shiny::reactivePoll()` might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return something in the `checkFunc` function, here you only print some messages and you always return `""`. In `valueFunc` you have to return the path to the image. Then `data()` (and not `data`) will return the path. Finally you have to correctly use `renderImage` (by looking at `?renderImage`).

```
  data <- reactivePoll(1000, session,
    checkFunc = function() {
      IMG <- paste0("C:/Windows/Web/Wallpaper/Theme2/img",input$SN,".jpg")
      if (file.exists(IMG))
        file.info(IMG)$mtime[1]
      else
        ""
    },
    valueFunc = function() {
      paste0("C:/Windows/Web/Wallpaper/Theme2/img",input$SN,".jpg")
    }
  )

  output$Display <- renderImage({
    list(src = data())
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the great sharing. I would like to share the digestion of my several silly questions and great answers.

My attention is to monitor a specific image folder, get a specfic one, manipulate the imge, and desplay the image plus some info in datatable. Here is the result, tons of issues to be improved certainly, yet I think, many shiny-newby has the same questions, and I would like to contribute to the community. Here is my ugly code, dare to share.

```
library(shiny)
library(magrittr)
library(imager)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarPanel(
  textOutput(outputId = "FILENAME"),
  dataTableOutput(outputId = "FILEINFO")
),
mainPanel(imageOutput(outputId = "DISPLAY")))


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$FILENAME <- renderText(Target.File)
  output$FILEINFO <- renderDataTable(datatable({
    file.info(Target.File)
  }))
  output$DISPLAY <- renderImage({
    tempF <<- tempfile(fileext = ".png")
    File.List <- list.files(pattern = ".*g$")
    Target.File <- File.List[which(substr(File.List, 1, 1) == "D")]
    load.image(Target.File) %>% 
      resize(100, 100) %>% 
      grayscale() %>% 
      save.image(tempF)
    list(src = tempF)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: my ugly but 1st shinyApp]